# Create functions inside Shiny Server with UI(input$NAME) as input for the function

Tags: r, shiny

I was trying to create functions to simulate cash flows, and it seems that shiny doesn't accept creating functions within it
It seems that shiny doesn't accept me to create functions inside it with the inputs coming from the user interface:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(FinCal)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("investimento_inicial",0,0),
  numericInput("periodo",0,0),
  numericInput("quantidade_mensal",0,0),
  numericInput("preco",0,0),
  numericInput("custo_fixo",0,0),
  numericInput("salario_funcionario",0,0),
  numericInput("numero_funcionarios",0,0),
  numericInput("taxa_mensal",0,0),
  numericInput("redutor",0,0),
  numericInput("tempo_inicio",0,0),
  numericInput("capacidade",0,0),
  numericInput("chancesucesso",0,0),
  numericInput("tempo_final",0,0),
  numericInput("reducao_lucrounitariomeio",0,0),
  numericInput("reducao_qtdmeio",0,0),
  numericInput("aumento_cfmeio",0,0),
  numericInput("reducao_lucrounitariofinal",0,0),
  numericInput("reducao_qtdfinal",0,0),
  numericInput("aumento_cffinal",0,0),
  numericInput("venda_final",0,0),
  numericInput("iniciopreco",0,0),
  numericInput("finalpreco",0,0),
  numericInput("iniciocv",0,0),
  numericInput("finalcv",0,0),
  numericInput("iniciocf",0,0),
  numericInput("finalcf",0,0),
  numericInput("iniciodemanda",0,0),
  numericInput("finaldemanda",0,0),
  verbatimTextOutput("table")
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$table=renderPrint({  
  
  risco2<-function(input$investimento_inicial,input$periodo,input$quantidade_mensal,input$preco,input$custo_fixo,input$custo_unitario,
                   input$salario_funcionario,input$numero_funcionarios,input$taxa_mensal,input$redutor,input$tempo_inicio,input$capacidade,input$chancesucesso,input$tempo_final,
                   input$reducao_lucrounitariomeio,input$reducao_qtdmeio,input$aumento_cfmeio,input$reducao_lucrounitariofinal,input$reducao_qtdfinal,input$aumento_cffinal,input$venda_final,
                   input$iniciopreco,input$finalpreco,input$iniciocv,input$finalcv,input$iniciocf,input$finalcf,input$iniciodemanda,input$finaldemanda ){
    input$custo_fixo<-input$custo_fixo+input$salario_funcionario*input$numero_funcionarios
    lunitario<-input$preco-input$custo_unitario
    
    duracao1<-(input$periodo-input$tempo_inicio-input$tempo_final)/2
    cashflow<-c(-input$investimento_inicial,
                rep(c(sum(lunitario*input$quantidade_mensal-(lunitario*input$quantidade_mensal*input$redutor))-input$custo_fixo),input$tempo_inicio), 
                rep(c(sum(lunitario*input$quantidade_mensal)-input$custo_fixo),duracao1), 
                rep(c(sum((1-input$reducao_lucrounitariomeio)*lunitario*input$quantidade_mensal*(1-input$reducao_qtdmeio))-input$custo_fixo*(1+input$aumento_cfmeio)),duracao1),
                rep(c(sum((1-input$reducao_lucrounitariofinal)*lunitario*(input$quantidade_mensal*(1-input$reducao_qtdfinal)))-input$custo_fixo*(1+input$aumento_cffinal) ),input$tempo_final),
                input$venda_final)
    
    npv(input$taxa_mensal,cashflow)
  }
  
  
  
})
  
}
```

`object 'input' not found`

How to create proper functions inside the shiny with the user interface inputs?

Comment: shiny `input$<name>` variables are variables that can be used as input for a defined function, but not in the function creation itself; see the answer of @MatCordTo

Answer (score 1):

I think you can first create the function inside the server and then enter the inputs as arguments of the function that you created previously.

```
server = function(input, output){

        sum           <- function(x,y){x+y}
        output$print1 <- renderPrint({sum(input$x,input$y)})
}
```